# Determine the category identifier of the category page template in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, qtranslate

This is something that has troubled me for the better part of the day. I created a new category.php template file for my girlfriend's cooking blog (you can see it [here](http://www.delscookingtwist.com)).

I wanted a specific layout for the category page - not the default one provided by the theme I use (Patchwork).

I googled around and eventually found that I could use the Wordpress PHP function `<?php single_cat_title( $prefix, $display ); ?>` as described in the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title). The point was then to use the Wordpress shortcode `[catlist]`. The shortcode can either take the category name or the category id.

I thought that would be it but unfortunately my girlfriend's blog is a bilingual one which means that `single_cat_title` doesn't always return the same value. It might return `recipe` in English and `recette` in French neither of which can be used to resolve the category in `[catlist]`. And if you think this is a corner case for bilingual blogs, it's not... It also applies to blogs that have categories with the same name (as to why you would have that, I don't know...)

All the other methods I could find were all specific to [the_loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and not applicable in my case.

Anyway, I thought I would share the answer below for everyone's benefit. When I found it, it made my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to retrieve the current object identifier (be it a post, category, tag...) is to use the lower-level Wordpress objects and namely:

```
$wp_query->get_queried_object_id()
```

as described in Wordpress's [class reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). The trick is to know the method name that gives you the property and Wordpress doesn't tell you that.

The closest described method is `get_queried_object()` (see [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object)).

The final template for my page is as follows:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying posts in the category view.
 *
 */
 get_header(); ?>

        <div id="primary" class="site-content">
                        <h1><?php single_cat_title("");?></h1>
            <div id="content" role="main">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[catlist id='.$wp_query->get_queried_object_id().' orderby=date order=DESC excerpt=yes excerpt_size=25 thumbnail=yes numberposts=-1 template=del]'); ?>                
            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary .site-content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```